# Fazer download async com WebClient.DownloadFileAsync

Tags: c#, async, asynctask, task

Hoje tenho uma classe que faz download de fotos, porém como são muitas fotos sempre acima de 5mil acho que poderia tirar proveito com metodo async. Processar várias task ao mesmo tempo.

Porém acho que estou fazendo confusões com Task<> e Async

```
 foreach (var item in Produto)
            {
                foreach (var foto in item.Fotos)
                {
                    var NovoNome = txt_IDC.Text + "_" + DownloadImagem.GerarNomeJPG(10);
                        var dImg = new DownloadImagem
                        {
                            NewNomeFile = NovoNome,
                            PathSave = pathFormulario,
                            UrlFoto = foto.UrlFoto
                        };

                        dImg.Download();
                        foto.NomeFoto = NovoNome;
                        }
                }
            }
```

e a minha dImg.Download(); chama o método que queria transformar em multiplos downloads ao mesmo tempo.

hoje está assim:

```
    public class DownloadImagem
    {
        public string UrlFoto { get; set; }
        public string PathSave { get; set; }
        public string NewNomeFile { get; set; }

    public void Download()
            {
                        using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
                        {

                            var pathfinal = PathSave + NewNomeFile;
                            var uri = new Uri(UrlFoto);
                            cliente.DownloadFileAsync(uri, pathfinal); //só isso já serve?
                          //  cliente.DownloadFile(UrlFoto, pathfinal); //assim é como estava
                        }
            }
}
```

Achei uma pergunta com algo que gostaria, mas não consegui entender a lógica
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/real-world-async-and-await-code-example

**EDIT:**
Tentei fazer assim:
  `dImg.DownloadAsync();` //aqui normal na classe DownloadImage que mudei para

```
public async void DownloadAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Download());
        }

 public void Download()
        {
                    using (WebClient cliente = new WebClient())
                    {

                        var pathfinal = PathSave + NewNomeFile;
                        var uri = new Uri(UrlFoto);

                        cliente.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
                        cliente.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
                        cliente.DownloadFileAsync(uri, pathfinal);
                    }
        }


        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Mas obtenho

> Você não pode iniciar uma operação assíncrona neste momento. Você pode
>   iniciar uma operação assíncrona somente dentro de um gerente ou um
>   módulo assíncrona ou durante certos eventos do ciclo de vida da
>   página. Se a exceção ocorreu durante a execução de uma página,
>   verifique se ele é marcado como <% @ Page Async = "true"%>. Essa
>   exceção também pode indicar uma tentativa de chamada para um método de
>   "assíncrono vazio", normalmente não suportados na elaboração dos
>   pedidos ASP.NET. O método assíncrono deve retornar uma tarefa e o
>   chamador tem que esperar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu precisei fazer algo parecido recentemente, segue o meu código abaixo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ToDo();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async void ToDo()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Download());
    }

    public static void Download()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri ur = new Uri("http://www.culturamix.com/wp-content/gallery/homer-1/homer-simpson.jpg");
        //   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += WebClientDownloadProgressChanged;
        client.DownloadDataCompleted += WebClientDownloadCompleted;
        client.DownloadFileAsync(ur, @"C:\Users\tadriano\Pictures\homer-simpson.jpg");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    static void WebClientDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Download status: {0}%.", e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    static void WebClientDownloadCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Download finished!");
    }
}
```